# [Android][Maven] Cannot find androidx artifacts

Tags: android, maven, pom.xml, android-library

I want to push my aar library package to Github Packages.
I created a pom.xml file with my github package link and all dependencies.

Here is the pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mypackage.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>aar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>My Package</name>
    <url>https://mywebsite.com</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0</version>

                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <sign>
                        <debug>false</debug>
                    </sign>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.lifecycle</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.fragment</groupId>
            <artifactId>fragment</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.recyclerview</groupId>
            <artifactId>recyclerview</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.recyclerview</groupId>
            <artifactId>recyclerview-selection</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.android.volley</groupId>
            <artifactId>volley</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.appcompat</groupId>
            <artifactId>appcompat</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android.material</groupId>
            <artifactId>material</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.legacy</groupId>
            <artifactId>legacy-support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven_central_repo</id>
            <name>Maven repo</name>
            <url>https://maven.google.com/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>github</id>
            <name>GitHub Packages</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/myrepo/myrepo</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

When deploying, I get the following error :
`The following artifacts could not be resolved: androidx.fragment:fragment:jar:1.0.0`

I get the error for all androidx dependencies that are downloaded from the Google Maven repository.

It seems that my file is getting androidx.fragment as a *jar* file, even if I specified the type as *pom*.

How can I get the androidx dependencies ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have configured the Maven/Gradle Google repository but the id and name you use belongs to a different repo. May be that confuses Maven. Use a unique ID and name.

Comment: Thanks. How can I find the right ID ?

Comment: You can define the ID, its just has to be unique. Best use something that reflects the repository like `<id>Google</id>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `maven-publish` plugin to auto-generate your pom file and publish. There is the example [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin).

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

// Because the components are created only during the afterEvaluate phase, you must
// configure your publications using the afterEvaluate() lifecycle method.

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            // Creates a Maven publication called "release".
            release(MavenPublication) {
                // Applies the component for the release build variant.
                from components.release

                // You can then customize attributes of the publication as shown below.
                groupId = 'com.example.MyLibrary'
                artifactId = 'final'
                version = '1.0'
            }
            // Creates a Maven publication called “debug”.
            debug(MavenPublication) {
                // Applies the component for the debug build variant.
                from components.debug

                groupId = 'com.example.MyLibrary'
                artifactId = 'final-debug'
                version = '1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I'm using Github Actions as a pipeline. When is afterEvaluate triggered ? If I build locally is it going to publish too ?

Comment: After you add this task, it will generate new tasks as described here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:tasks @jreid

Comment: It should publish when you call `./gradlew publish`, it shouldn't publish after your local builds @jreid

Comment: Thanks it was a mistake from my side. I accepted the answer. Big help !